# Eloquent ORM PHP retrieve movies which have related comment or review

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent

I'm having the following tables (and Models) with attributes:

```
Comments:
- id
- movie_id
- date

Reviews:
- id
- movie_id
- date

Movies:
- id
```

Using PostgreSQL with Eloquent ORM & Slim 3 framework.
I'm trying to retrieve all:

Note: There can be many comments and reviews for a movie, but only the last review (BIGGEST ID) is interesting..

> Movies which has: Comments OR\AND Reviews WHERE their date > (NOW-1 day).

Tries write it in a SQL with JOINS, but figured out that i can use some of the Eloquent more advanced and simple to read functions.. 
But so far, Drowned in all the options, and couldn't find the right method to use..
Any Help to make it the most efficient and lighted as possible?

Thanks!
Itay.

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: Tries using the "whereHas" along "orWhereHas" and then add the "with" to the builder, but it builds a massive syntax which i sure can be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine these are your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
    movie_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    movie TEXT
) ;

CREATE TABLE comments
(
    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(movie_id),
    comment_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date,
    comment TEXT
) ;

CREATE TABLE reviews
(
    review_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(movie_id),
    review_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date,
    review TEXT
) ;
```

And their values:

```
INSERT INTO
    movies
    (movie)
VALUES
    ('2001 A Space Odissey'),
    ('Start Trek: The Wrath of Khan'),
    ('Start Trek Beyond'),
    ('The 39 steps');

INSERT INTO
    comments
    (movie_id, comment_date, comment)
VALUES
    (1, current_date,   'Best film ever'),
    (2, current_date+1, 'Not as good as 2001');

INSERT INTO reviews
    (movie_id, review_date, review)
VALUES
    (3, current_date, 'Not the best Start Trek film ever, however, the best CGI imaginable, ...') ;
```

The easier way to accomplish what you want, is to first get (all) movies, and max(review_id), max(comment_id), limiting them by date:

```
SELECT
    m.movie_id, m.movie, max(r.review_id) AS review_id, max(c.comment_id) AS comment_id
FROM
    movies m
    LEFT JOIN reviews r ON (r.movie_id = m.movie_id AND r.review_date >= current_date)
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON (c.movie_id = m.movie_id AND c.comment_date >= current_date) 
GROUP BY
    m.movie_id ;
```

```
movie_id | movie                         | review_id | comment_id
-------: | :---------------------------- | --------: | ---------:
       2 | Start Trek: The Wrath of Khan |      null |          2
       4 | The 39 steps                  |      null |       null
       1 | 2001 A Space Odissey          |      null |          1
       3 | Start Trek Beyond             |         1 |       null
```

From the previous query, we link back to get the rest of the review and comment data:

```
SELECT
    q.movie_id, q.movie, q.review_id, r2.review_date, r2.review, q.comment_id, c2.comment_date, c2.comment
FROM
    (SELECT
        m.movie_id, m.movie, max(r.review_id) AS review_id, max(c.comment_id) AS comment_id
    FROM
        movies m
        LEFT JOIN reviews r ON (r.movie_id = m.movie_id AND r.review_date >= current_date)
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON (c.movie_id = m.movie_id AND c.comment_date >= current_date) 
    GROUP BY
        m.movie_id
    HAVING
        -- restrict to only movies with some recent comment or review
        max(r.review_id) IS NOT NULL or max(comment_id) IS NOT NULL
    ) AS q
    LEFT JOIN reviews r2 USING(review_id)
    LEFT JOIN comments c2 USING(comment_id)
ORDER BY
    movie_id ;
```

The result is:

```
movie_id | movie                         | review_id | review_date | review                                                                   | comment_id | comment_date | comment            
-------: | :---------------------------- | --------: | :---------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------: | :----------- | :------------------
       1 | 2001 A Space Odissey          |      null | null        | null                                                                     |          1 | 2017-07-30   | Best film ever     
       2 | Start Trek: The Wrath of Khan |      null | null        | null                                                                     |          2 | 2017-07-31   | Not as good as 2001
       3 | Start Trek Beyond             |         1 | 2017-07-30  | Not the best Start Trek film ever, however, the best CGI imaginable, ... |       null | null         | null
```

You can test all this in *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6788eaa8683e892d06445a2066a08885)*

---

NOTE: I honestly don't know how to back-translate this to Eloquent. ORMs are good for simple queries, but when things get a little bit complicated, I prefer to go back to SQL.

Comment: Amazing answer! Although, I do preffer to accomplish it in ORM, I Wonder the efficient of this SQL, and run-time, will have to check it out, 
I Will wait to see if somebody manage to translate it to ORM style, and will accept this answer if not.
Thank you Joanolo!